# Put a frame around two aligned pictures

Tags: graphics

I have two aligned pictures in my text (sideways). I was wondering, if it is possible to put a frame around both pictures.

Many thanks and have a nice weekend

Example:

```
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering\includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth]{"picture1"}
      \includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth]{"picutre2"}
\caption{Figure 1}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping the figures e.g in a `\fbox`.

```
\fbox{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth]{"picture1"}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth]{"picture1"}%
}
```

You also can customize the appearance of the frame. For example, include

```
\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{3pt}%
```

before the `\fbox` command.